# BJT amplifier design

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt, design, common-emitter

I am trying to design a BJT amplifier with the given parameters and limitations. The circuit is shown below.

[image]

Parameters:

- Vcc = 15 V
- RL = 20 kΩ
- beta = 180
- Vbe(on)= 0.6 V
- C<sub>µ</sub> = C<sub>π</sub> = 0

Limitations are:

1. Swing voltage of V<sub>out</sub> must be between 22 and 24 V (peak to peak)
2. Voltage gain must be more than 10
3. Power dissipation by resistors must be under 0.2 W
4. Corner frequencies of C<sub>1</sub>, C<sub>2</sub>, and C<sub>E</sub> should be < 10 Hz
5. The high threshold frequency should be 20 kHz

I assumed that Rc must be smaller than RL so I designed Rc= 2 k ohms and then I found RE1 = 180 ohms, but I have an issue where I have to design RE2. I don't know how to use 22-24 V pk-pk specification in this design.

- How do I adjust peak to peak voltage?
- How can I calculate input and output impedances and open circuit voltage gain?
- How do I approach power dissipation considerations?

As it's a homework question, I'm not looking for a whole solution, but some tips and advice.

Comment: Because it is homework you need to show some effort at solving this to give an indication as to where you are stuck.

Comment: *...begin?* perhaps trying **Rc** smaller than **RL**. Then work out resistors to satisfy DC bias in the transistor's linear region. Expect to refine your initial choice of resistor values later when other specs are difficult to attain. 24V pk-pk spec will be the first one I'd try to achieve. Perhaps it is *assumed* to be a linear amplifier, but no mention of this is made, a "cheat" might allow a non-linear amplifier (which is a bit easier to design) - however the gain spec of ten is at risk of violation.

Comment: What background do you have in this problem -- what has been covered in class so far, by the instructor, handouts, textbook? What BJT circuits have you analyzed so far? What level of analysis are you comfortable with (DC or AC steady state, dependent sources, nodal analysis, etc.)?

Comment: @Andyaka I actually tried to solve it by myself. I assumed that Rc must be smaller than RL so I designed Rc= 2 k ohms and then I found RE1 = 180 ohms. But I have an issue where I have to design RE2. I don't know how to use 22-24 V pk-pk specification in this design.

Comment: @TimWilliams I used Microelectronics Circuits and Design by Donald A. Neamen and covered the first part of the book Semiconductor Devices and Basic Amplifiers

Comment: It's just that you said this: *How can I start to design the circuit, where should I begin* --> so you did know how to start and those values seem close to being right to me. Now think about the quiescent voltage at the collector and how that defines the current through Rc and, in turn how that defines the quiescent voltage on the emitter and, how that would influence the bias resistor selection.... So, amend your question by deleting your statement about not knowing where to start and, replace it with what you said above in comments.

Comment: Also to clarify, +/-Vcc is symmetrical, so the total supply is 30V?

Comment: Regarding RE2, how much AC voltage does it have across it? How much DC? What effect would that DC have on the rest of the circuit? Other voltages, or range of voltages, perhaps?

Comment: @Andyaka thank you at first I thought that my starting point is wrong so I said where should I begin.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes total supply is 30V, there aren't any clarifications about the issues that you've mentioned.

Comment: I mean to say, your starting point is reasonable enough, and am asking leading questions to suggest a possible route of further solution.

Comment: @Aldocest Operation at an exactly stable temperature? Or over some range? (That output voltage swing spec is very tight.)

Comment: The quiescent voltage on the collector should be close to zero in order to achieve the + and - swing between the power supply rails. Maybe start there.

Comment: @Aldocest #5 suggests to me that the gain must roll-off at 20 kHz. Since C1 and C2 are high-pass, not low-pass, they won't be causing any low-pass roll-off. The only remaining capacitor is CE. But with RE about 200 Ohm (your estimate), this suggests the RC time constant must be close to 8 us. However, spec #4 directly contradicts this. The only conclusion I can reach is that #5 doesn't specify a roll-off at 20 kHz but only says that the amplifier must work at least out to 20 kHz. But much higher is fine. Is that how you interpret #5?

Comment: @Aldocest Have you disappeared from the world? Or still interested in the topic?

Answer (score 0):

Just some of my initial thoughts. Perhaps they may help:

- Your specifications appear to hold a fixed \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ value. This **never** happens, in practice. In fact, \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ is continually changing with the applied signal and will distort the output and complicate (somewhat) the situation with such a tight peak-to-peak limitation range. But as luck would have it, you don't need to care about this reality. Nice. This means that you don't have to deal with \$r_e^{\,'}\$ as there's no dynamic resistance, which leads into the next note:
- For purposes of arranging the specified **loaded** voltage gain of \$A_v=10\$, you treat the collector resistor as being in parallel with the load. So, this means your goal is to have \$\frac{R_{_\text{C}}\,\mid\mid\,R_{_\text{L}}}{R_{_{\text{E}_{1}}}}=A_v\$.
- I'd select \$23\:\text{V}_{_\text{PP}}\$ (roughly) to allow some margin and I'd constrain the loaded gain to just slightly more than the allowed 10. So the required input will be \$2\frac14\:\text{V}_{_\text{PP}}\$ and the loaded voltage gain will be taken as \$A_v\approx 10.2\$.
- \$C_{_\text{E}}\$ will be taken to be large enough that its voltage remains fixed.

The power constraint may prevent success. The smaller you make \$R_{_\text{C}}\$ the closer the collector swing is to the specified swing on the load and this helps better fit it within the rails. But it increases the quiescent current required. And that is something that cannot be easily afforded. And if you focus on keeping the power manageable by reducing the quiescent current and increasing \$R_{_\text{C}}\$, the circuit must handle an ever-increasing collector swing. And that is also something that cannot be easily afforded. I've not spent enough time on this and I may have made a mistake, but a back-of-envelope calc suggests some worry.